# "Strange" C# syntax

Tags: c#, syntax

I just saw this in a project I downloaded from Code Project:

```
base.DialogResult = this.Result != null;
```

I don't consider myself new to C# but this one is new to me. Can anyone tell me what's going on with this statement?

**Edit** Great answers, thanks. I've just never used that before.

Comment: we can't call it "strange". it's like "bool toto = this.Result != null;base.DialogResult =toto;"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you add parens it's easier to read (and understand). The logical comparison operator `!=` precedes the assignment operator `=`:

```
base.DialogResult = (this.Result != null);
```

The same statement, even more verbose:

```
if (this.Result != null)
    base.DialogResult = true;
else
    base.DialogResult = false;
```

Comment: Is that like a short-circuit if statment?

Comment: The result of a comparison is a boolean, and that value gets assigned to the left side.

Comment: yep, it is a short-circuit if statment

Comment: @John: Is there another kind of `if` statement?

Comment: @Marcelo - for me, not anymore :)

Comment: There is no short-circuit behavior here.

Answer (score 4):

`this.Result != null` evaluates to a boolean, `true` or `false`.

The result of the evaluation is set in the `DialogResult` member of the base class.

Not strange at all, it's just an assignment.

Answer (score 3):

The `!=` (not equal) operator has precedence over the `=` (assignment) operator.

Answer (score 2):

Thats simple, basically it assigns the result of the expression

```
this.Result != null
```

to

```
base.DialogResult
```

the expression uses the in-equality operator, so it returns either true or false, depending on wether this.Result is null or not

Answer (score 0):

That means:

```
bool g = (this.Result != null);
this.DialogResult = g;
```